# Function changeColor with some problems when passing Hex color (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have a function that works fine when I pass into the function ('yellow', 'blue'). On click change the color, another click change again.
But if I pass ('#404040', 'blue'), it only works one time, the color goes to #404040 but if I click again nothing happens.

I don´t know why this is happening, everything looks ok to me. Can anyone help pls?

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(bgColor, textColor) {

    var textClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");

    var spanColor = document.getElementById("spanColor");
    spanColor.style.background = bgColor;


    if (document.body.style.background != bgColor) {

        document.body.style.background = bgColor;

        for (var i = 0; i < textClassElements.length; i++) {
                
            textClassElements.item(i).style.color = textColor;
        }

    }
    else{

        document.body.style.background = 'red';
        spanColor.style.background = 'red';

        for (var i = 0; i < textClassElements.length; i++) {
                
            textClassElements.item(i).style.color = textColor;
        }
    }
    
};
```

HTML:

```
 <li class="list-3"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('#404040', 'blue');">MUDA TEMA</a></li>
```

Comment: `console.log(document.body.style.background);`

Comment: @epascarello How so? Where should I place that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. Like @DaveB said yellow returns yellow so the if and else works fine, while hex colors don´t return the "hex" so it never enters the else....

So, what I did was to place a flag, the flag needs to be outside the function otherwise every time we clicked the function the flag would be always false...

Here is the code:

```
var flag=false;
function changeColor(bgColor, textColor) {

    var textClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");

    var spanColor = document.getElementById("spanColor");
    spanColor.style.background = bgColor;

    

    if (flag == false) {

        flag=true;

        document.body.style.background = bgColor;

        for (var i = 0; i < textClassElements.length; i++) {
                
            textClassElements.item(i).style.color = textColor;
        }

    }
    else{

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        for (var i = 0; i < textClassElements.length; i++) {
                
            textClassElements.item(i).style.color = textColor;
        }

        flag=false;
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following line of code:

`if (document.body.style.background != bgColor) {`

When `document.body.style.background` is set to `yellow` then `document.body.style.background` returns `yellow`.

But when `document.body.style.background` is set to `#404040` then calls that read the property `document.body.style.background` return `'rgb(64, 64, 64)'` so the result of the `if` is always true so the color never changes again.

Color logic would best be avoided in Javascript and rather held in a CSS class which could  be read or written to the element that you wish to change.

Comment: I see. So the only solution is to use colors with "name" or to create a function that adds a class in CSS when clicked?

Comment: @DGF That isn't the only solution but might be one that keeps with separation of concerns and ease of change in the future. If you want to write code to check and parse the rgb text strings for comparison, you could do that too. It might not be that much code. I am not really sure. The choice of solutions is yours.

Comment: Thanks @DaveB, I solved it. I posted the answer, thanks for the input.